# toilet issues with my cat

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I have an 18 month old calico female cat. I have to work during the day so I leave her to roam and don't lock her in any certain rooms. She's an indoor cat who uses a kitty litter, which is cleaned every time she uses it.

Over the past month she has pooped once and had a wee once on my throw, on my sofa where I sit. She had a wee in my bath, too, by the plug hole last week while I was on the loo myself. I'm at my wits end with it now and don't have any idea why she's doing this. Can anyone give me any ideas how to stop her from doing this and give me some advice on what to do?

My other kitty who I had for 18years(who died 5 years ago now) never did anything like this so I don't know why my kitty is doing this now.

Comment: Breaking litter box protocol is often a signal that the cat is not feeling well. A trip to the vet may be in order.

Answer (score 4):

**Take her to the vet!**

This can be a sign of some pretty serious diseases, including cancer. There is pretty much no reason for her to start going some place else inconsistently. I would take her to the vet as soon as possible. If the vet says it's nothing, I would first of all make sure there is no loud or even "quiet" noises constantly in the area of the litter box. If there is, they might be scaring your cat away.

Also, could you tell us if your cat is spay/neutered? If she isn't, this may help. If you are going to move your cat's litter box, do so **slowly.** abrupt moving of their property can disturb a cat. Move it about a foot each day. This can be tedious but almost never fails.

Other reasons she may not be going in her litter box include:

- people frequently walking past;
- litter box not offering privacy or being being closed off - please note that your cat needs about two exits from the litter box;
- having to go too far to get to it.

There should be 1 litter box per story in your house, including the basement and then 1 more. For example, let's say you have a 2 story house, and a basement, you would have 4 litter boxes.

Hope this helped. Best of luck.

Comment: Disagree re two exits from litter box; I have never seen that be an issue even in multi-cat households. Box per storey plus one seems like serious overkill unless you have a large clowder or cats who are old and/or infirm. Privacy needs vary from cat to cat but that can be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have three cats. One of them is very agressive with food, so I feed her after the other two have eaten (they know how to share). I used to lock her out of the room, feed the other two and then go to the toilet (my morning routine). She would pee in the bath almost every day because of food anxiety. I have now changed my routine where I lock all three of them in a room where they have a litter tray while I go to the toilet. She still has food anxiety but at least she now goes in the litter tray instead of the bath. I then remove her from the room and feed the other two first.

It's hard to know exactly what's going on with your cat without observing her directly. Does she go to the toilet in inappropriate places only while you're at work? It could be separation anxiety.

Answer (score 0):

My cat is neutered already and her litter tray is always clean as I clean it after every use, but I read on Google it could be a sign of separation anxiety as I've just started a new 9 too 5 job, so I'm not with her all day now. My cat is also in good health, but to use the loo I sit on is very strange to me, and I live in a ground floor flat so I only need one litter tray and my lola can get to it easily. Thanks for the advice and I've never seen a cat litter box with two exits.

Comment: If your worried about separation anxiety, try relax my cat. It's very effective. Look it up on youtube and play the appropriate song for your scenario. I know personally it works very well. Also, you could try leaving this TV on. Again, these are just suggestions, your litter box doesn't HAVE to have two exits, it's just a good idea.

Answer (score -3):

First, not neutering a cat is animal cruelty or it will unavoidably lead to animal cruelty.

Second, not only male cats have territory, in a lesser sense, also the females have.

Third, she doesn't know that peeing on the kitten litter is a requirement, because you can't explain it to her. She used it only because always this had already a pee odor. She doesn't know, why would be any problem with changing this place to another location.

- She need to understand, where is the toilet. For a while, don't clean it after all usage, do it only after all second.
- Be careful, while on toilet, and after a while, exclusively positive experiences should happen to she!
- If you find her pee/faeces elsewhere, take him to that place and move her nose to "that". Don't touch it, it would be cruel, but it is important to feel the odor more strongly as she would like it. "Explain" here that you are now **very** angry. Push her down (don't cause pain! But you can make it unpleasant), give threatening voices, while you still hold her.
- If you see that she needs to use the toilet, move she to the litter and give her many love, until she doesn't do her "task". The thinking of the cats is very location-oriented. If you move she to any place, she understands very well, that you want she to be on that place. They see no reason to follow your wishes too long, but they understand it. If you move she to the litter while see needs to pee, she will understand very well: you want she too pee on the litter.
- Any time **after** she uses the ordinary toilet, give she many love. (Don't touch or even near she while she is on it!)

So it will work, don't worry, I had never cats who hadn't understood already the first "lesson" very well. I've seen on them. First, they simply don't want to pee (s*) for a while. After they can't hold it any more, they start to think, what to do. They are looking for a place to pee, and they are looking to you. *It is visible on them, as they learn: peeing on the cat litter didn't lead to a bad event with you. Only peeing next to the bed. And they go to the cat litter.*

The important thing is: they don't understand, *why* is it important for you. They don't think in "why"s. To them, peeing beside the bed would be okay, they can't see any bad in it.

But, honestly, already 3-4 week old kitten use the toilet from themselves, and they learn - from the odor - where is the place where they have to pee (s*).